# Asus Transformer - Show Virtual Keyboard When Docked

Tags: keyboard, asus-eee-pad-transformer, docking-station

Asus Transformer tablet provides a dock with a hardware keyboard. I can not find information on showing the virtual (on-screen) keyboard while being docked. Is it possible?
It is Android 3.2.1.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's your use case for this? It seems like it wouldn't really provide any benefit (irrespective of whether or not it's even possible).

Comment: Believe it or not, but Connectbot ssh client does not provide a way to press '@' or '$' from the physical keyboard! At the same time, the virtual keyboard does not provide arrows. Both arrows and dollars are needed for a lot of console work.

Comment: Interesting. It seems rather odd for those characters to be unavailable with the hardware keyboard.

Comment: They are, but Connectbot treats shift strangely.

Comment: Actually, regarding your second comment about the virtual keyboard lacking arrows: have you tried [Hacker's Keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en)? It's not an answer to this question, but it could be a reasonable stopgap for you perhaps (don't know how it interacts with Connectbot specifically, though).

Comment: There is a modified version of connectbot that fixes the shift-number problem and some others:  https://github.com/lorantkurthy/connectbot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's simple: when the hardware keyboard is attached, the tray (lower right of screen) has a keyboard icon. Click it and the top option is use hardware keyboard on/off.